# Where is this counterterm coming from?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, renormalization, feynman-diagrams

Given the Lagrangian in 6-dimensional spacetime:

$$
L = \frac{1}{2}\partial^\mu\phi\partial_\mu\phi - \frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2-\frac{g_3}{3!}\phi^3.\tag{1}
$$

The Lagrangian with counterterms is given by

$$
L_c = \frac{1}{2}Z\partial^\mu\phi\partial_\mu\phi - \frac{1}{2}(m^2+\delta_m^2)\phi^2\color{red}{-Z_1g_1\phi}-Z_3\frac{g_3}{3!}\phi^3\\
= \frac{1}{2}\partial^\mu\phi\partial_\mu\phi - \frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2-\frac{g_3}{3!}\phi^3 +\frac{1}{2}(\partial^\mu\phi\partial_\mu\phi)\delta_z-\frac{1}{2}\delta_m^2\phi^2\color{red}{-\delta_1\phi}-\delta_3\frac{\phi^3}{3!}.\tag{2}
$$

How does the term $\color{red}{-Z_1g_1\phi}$ and $\color{red}{-\delta_1\phi}$ appear? The superficial degree of divergence of a graph in 6 dimensions could be found as
$$
\omega = 6-2n\tag{3}
$$

where $n$ is the number of external lines. To find the one-particle irreducible divergent graphs, we can set $n = 1,2,3$. It seems to me that those terms in the Lagrangian are associated with the $n=1$ case.

However, for $n = 2$ and $3$, it's more clear to me where the counterterms come from, because $\delta_m$, $\delta_z$, and $\delta_3$ are 'attached' to some existing quantities. I don't know how to understand why  $\color{red}{-Z_1g_1\phi}$ and $\color{red}{-\delta_1\phi}$ are added to the Lagrangian.

Also, I'm not confident with implementing $Z$ factors. I would really appreciate it if someone could explain a bit about the first line of $L_c$. Why and how the $Z$ factors are attached?

Comment: Which reference? Link to abstract page? Which page? Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/741774/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks, this actually comes from a question on my lecture note.

Answer (score 3):

The linear term has to be included to cancel tadpole diagrams, AKA diagrams with one external leg and its embedded variants in more complicated diagrams. For $\phi^3$ you've got the $O(\lambda)$ term $$-i\delta_1-\frac{i\lambda}{2}\int d^dk \ \frac{i}{k^2-m^2+i\epsilon}$$ which has to be set to zero by tuning $\delta_1$. The problem is not only that this term is divergent, but also the fact that the LSZ theorem requires a zero vaccum expectation value to project out the correct particle states.

The factors of $Z$ and $\delta$ in your Lagrangian are there to make your Lagrangian depend on the regulator parameter ($\Lambda$, $\epsilon$, $a$ depending on your regularization scheme) so that they can be made to cancel the divergent quantities in observables when the physical limit is taken (e.g. $\Lambda\to\infty$).

Answer (score 2):

There is already a correct answer by AfterShave. The point is that one must for consistency as a minimum include all possible renormalizable terms that are not excluded by symmetry, such as a tadpole term $Z_1g_1\phi$, cf. the [totalitarian principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totalitarian_principle), even if they were absent at some scale.  Perhaps this is most easily seen from the perspective of the [Wilsonian effective action](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=wilsonian+effective+action), cf. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/700619/2451).

For other examples, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/122620/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/380520/2451) related Phys.SE posts.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer! In my new question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/742267/, we can still cancel the divergence from the diagrams with $b = 1, 3, 4; f = 0$, so why don't we include them in the Lagrangian with counter terms?

Comment: We indeed should include them by the totalitarian principle.

Comment: 1. Thanks, so if we include them, do we need additional terms (like $g\phi^3+\lambda\phi^4$) in the original Lagrangian? 2. If we just write $L$ as what it is in my new question, do we still need $\delta_3\phi^3$ and $\delta_4\phi^4$?

Comment: By 'original' Lagrangian you mean eq. (1)?

Comment: Yes, eq.(1) here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/742267/

Comment: If we don't have those terms in eq.(1), I think we can still have those counterterms, as they are not excluded.

Comment: 1. That depends on renormalization scheme. There is some freedom what part to put in the counterterm. 2. Yes.